# Get ArrayList from Object

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have one method that returns an object with two arraylists:

```
return new Object[] {work, play};
```

I am trying to get them back out in another method. I have tried casting to ArrayList but I get the error 'array required, but java.lang.Object found'.

```
ArrayList setWork = (ArrayList)obj[0];
ArrayList setPlay = (ArrayList)obj[1];
```

Full code for ArrayList creation:

```
public static Object[] getWorkandPlay(ArrayList al) {

    ArrayList work = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList play = new ArrayList();

    for (int i=0; i<al.size(); i++){
        String item = (String) al.get(i);

        if (item.startsWith("w.")) {
            System.out.println("w " + item);
            work.add(item);
        } else if (item.startsWith("p.")) {
            System.out.println("p " + item);
            play.add(item);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Entries must start with either w. or p.\n");
        }
    }
    return new Object[] {work, play};
}
```

Comment: Why are you returning `ArrayList`s inside an array of `Object`s?

Comment: can you past the code that declares and creates work and play?

Comment: From the error, it looks like obj is an object, not an object array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing something like this based on your code and it works...

```
class Test{
    public static Object[] getWorkandPlay(ArrayList al) {
        ArrayList work = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList play = new ArrayList();

        for (int i=0; i<al.size(); i++){
            String item = (String) al.get(i);

            if (item.startsWith("w.")) {
                System.out.println("w " + item);
                work.add(item);
            } else if (item.startsWith("p.")) {
                System.out.println("p " + item);
                play.add(item);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Entries must start with either w. or p.\n");
            }
        }
        return new Object[] {work, play};
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> al=new ArrayList<>();
        al.add("w. test");
        al.add("p. test");
        Object[] obj=getWorkandPlay(al);
        ArrayList setWork = (ArrayList)obj[0];
        ArrayList setPlay = (ArrayList)obj[1];
    }
}
```

output

```
w w. test
p p. test
```

Comment: I applied this to my code taking into account other methods and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

return new Object[]   {work, play};   i   think   returns   an   array   of   object.   Try   ArrayList   result   =   new   ArrayList();
put   work   andd play   inside   result   then   return   result.   Then

Answer (score 1):

In your calling code, you should set the reference type of obj as an Object array.
You probably have
`Object obj = getWorkandPlay(anArrayList);` in your code. Change it to `Object[] obj = getWorkandPlay(anArrayList);`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a **typo** somewhere in your code. This compiles for me:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SampleClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an ArrayList and add some sample Strings
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.add("w. test");
        al.add("p. test");

        Object[] obj = getWorkandPlay(al);

        ArrayList setWork = (ArrayList)obj[0];
        ArrayList setPlay = (ArrayList)obj[1];
    }

    public static Object[] getWorkandPlay(ArrayList al) {
        ArrayList work = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList play = new ArrayList();

        for (int i=0; i<al.size(); i++){
            String item = (String) al.get(i);

            if (item.startsWith("w.")) {
                System.out.println("w " + item);
                work.add(item);
            } else if (item.startsWith("p.")) {
                System.out.println("p " + item);
                play.add(item);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Entries must start with either w. or p.\n");
            }
        }

        return new Object[] {work, play};
    }
}
```